# Why does Number < String returns true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

EDIT: I will rephrase my question, I type Number < String and it returns true, also works when I do typeof(2) < typeof("2").

```
Number < String => true
typeof(2) < typeof("2") => true
```

I'm guessing it is the value of ASCII characters of each letter in Number and String but I am not sure if that is the reason this is returning true, and I want to know why does this happens, what processes or how does the interpreter gets to this result?

Comment: What is the point of comparing `Number` and `String` in the first place?

Comment: ASCII code for "S" is 83 and for "N" it's 78. Method charCodeAt() returns character code at first position. Number 78 is smaller that 83 so it evaluates true.

Comment: And yes, it's because the word "Number" sorts alphabetically before the word "String", but the actual strings involved are the results you'd get by calling `Number.toString()` and `String.toString()`

Comment: @epascarello ... "I type Number < String" - I am thinking that that's literally what was typed, and that would definitely give the quoted results.

Comment: In that case, yes, it compares the ASCII code of the first characters. When those are the same, it compares the second characters, until it finds a difference.

Comment: However, there is, of course, a difference between `"Number"` and `Number`. The latter can be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of

```
Number < String
```

is *not* the result of comparing the strings "Number" and "String", or not *exactly* that. It's the result of comparing the strings returned from `Number.toString()` and `String.toString()`. Those strings will (in all the runtimes I know of) have more stuff in them than just the strings "Number" and "String", but those two substrings will be the first place that they're different.

You can see what those actual strings are by typing

```
Number.toString()
```

in your browser console.

Comment: Agree. Correct explanation.

Answer (score 5):

**First answer:**

The charCodeAt() method returns the numeric Unicode value of the character at the given index. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

Now if you do not specify any index position then character at 0th index is considered. Now, `S` ASCII value is `83` and `N` ASCII value is `78`. so, you are getting those number. Check [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

And `78 < 83 => true` is obvious.

Try `"String".charCodeAt(1)` and you will get `116` which is ASCII value of `t`

---

**Second answer based on OP's edited question:**

Frankly speaking your comparison `Number < String` is "technically" incorrect because Less-than Operator `<` or any similar operator is for expressions, and `Number` and `String` are functions and not expressions. However *@Pointy* explained on how `Number < String` worked and gave you results.

## More insight on comparison operators

Comparison operators like `<` works on expressions, read [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.2). Typically, you should have a valid expression or resolved value for RHS and LHS.

Now this is the definition of expression, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) - "*An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value. Conceptually, there are two types of expressions: those that assign a value to a variable and those that simply have a value.*"

So, `(x = 7) < (x = 2)` or `new Number() < new String()` is a "technically" valid/good comparison, even this `Object.toString < Number.toString()` but really not `Object < Function`.

Below are rules/features for comparisons, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

- Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding positions.
- Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have the same number value). NaN is not equal to anything, including NaN. Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.
- Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or both are false.
- Two distinct objects are never equal for either strict or abstract comparisons.
- An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object.
- Null and Undefined Types are strictly equal to themselves and abstractly equal to each other.

Comment: You just got in before me. - Correct answer is correct.

Comment: @DanielTate Yeah bud. Anyways post your and I promise to +1 :)

Comment: This is more-or-less a fine answer, but I'm not sure it's an answer to the actual question. The OP was speculating that there's a character code comparison happening, and that's true, but the idea that the internals of the runtime actually involves calls to `.charCodeAt()` when comparing strings seems kind-of unlikely.

Comment: @hagrawal I'm sorry I didn't explain myself correctly, I updated the question for clarity

Comment: @Pointy I cannot help if OP changes his question. When I answered it was exactly answering his question.

Comment: @hagrawal yes, I agree; I was not really trying to say bad things about your answer, because it contains useful information.

Comment: @Pointy and Santiago: I had left for the day soon after my comment, so couldn't follow up until now. I have edited my answer and provided more insight.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does the following thing:

```
"String".charCodeAt(); => 83
"S".charCodeAt(); => 83
"String".charCodeAt(0); => 83
```

The method **charCodeAt(a)** gets the char code from position **a**. The default value is 0

If you compare *N > S* you will get *78 > 83 => true*

For the complete String Javascript calculates the sum of all ASCII char codes. 
So I can answer your question with yes.